# what is DATE_DIALOG_ID in DatePickerDialog examples

Tags: android, datepickerdialog

I'm an Android beginner.  Several examples on DatePickerDialog have a line of code such as DATE_DIALOG_ID = 999. (https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-date-picker-example/). This number is different in each example. I Googled this but couldn't find anything helpful.

I'm having trouble in general, understanding how to use DatePickerDialog. Is there a simplified tutorial available anywhere? All the examples I've seen so far have little description or code comments.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow please read [how to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: That tutorial is from 2011 and is using long-since-deprecated techniques. You would not use that ID when wrapping a `DatePickerDialog` in a `DialogFragment`. "I'm having trouble in general, understanding how to use DatePickerDialog" -- feel free to ask specific questions here in Stack Overflow. "Is there a simplified tutorial available anywhere?" -- asking for off-site resources is considered to be off-topic.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I'm so sorry, I'm new here. Will keep that in mind. And thanx for your comment. I didn't realize that was such an old post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a unique identifier for that dialog, so you can match against it in `onCreateDialog`. This method of showing Dialogs in deprecated in Android, and it is recommended instead to use `DialogFragment`, as seen here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

Comment: Thankyou, that was helpful! It seems I need to understand Fragments first, before I begin with DatePicker.